# PHP string equals check fails

Tags: php

I have a weird problem. I have checking a php string like this:

On Page1

```
$_SESSION['test']=<a value from a row fetched from db>
```

On Page2

```
$myVar=$_SESSION['test'];
echo $myVar;

if($myVar=="This is the match string"){
echo "Matched";
}else{
echo "Not Matched";
}
```

I can see that $myVar echoed out the same string that I am checking again "This is the match string" but it still goes into else. I tried:

```
$myVar=(string)trim($_SESSION['test']);
```

but it still goes into else. What can be the issue? Any idea?

Comment: Please do `var_dump($myVar, $matchString);` right before your if-statement, this will likely shed some light on the cause of your issue.

Comment: Use `var_dump($str);` to verify that they're really identical; no extraneous newlines etc. Also use some spaces and indentation.

Comment: Has the string unicode chars?

Comment: Try using `if (strcmp($myVar, "This is the match string") == 0) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible there are trailing blank spaces (space,tab, newline).

Try

```
$myVar = trim( $_SESSION['test'] );
```

Doing var_dump( $_SESSION['test'] ); might also reveal the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your string are really equal?
try var_dump($_SESSION['test']); and compare the two length and letters.